# GAE urlfetch returning 500 uncaught exception in production

Tags: google-app-engine, urlfetch

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

totango_url = "https://sdr.totango.com/pixel.png"
totango_url2 = "https://app.totango.com/images/accounts-users.png"
result = urlfetch.fetch(totango_url, validate_certificate=None )
print result.status_code
```

In production ,  request to `totango_url` logs indicate (with no error_detail) :

`DownloadError: Unable to fetch URL: https://sdr.totango.com/pixel.gif`

i ran this curl command. works fine from local setup , for both the https totango urls

`curl -v  "https://sdr.totango.com/pixel.gif"`

`curl -v "https://app.totango.com/images/accounts-users.png"`

The ssl certificates are valid and same for both urls.

using the urlfetch.fetch on both urls also returns 200 from my (local) datastore console.

However , the urlfetch.fetch calls to `https://sdr.totango.com/pixel.png` fails with the above error

Also , i ran the same code in the google cloud playground  tweaking the sample app-engine application and seem to get a 200 response for `totango_url2` while it returns a 500 for `totango_url`. Both have the same ssl certificate , i think.

is there some ip whitelisting /firewall issue that app-engine in production that i need to take care of?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like an issue on the remote side. If you're able to fetch that image from one place but not another, that speaks to the remote site doing some sort of filtering, possibly by IP address.

Comment: thank you for the input. Should i ask the remote service to check for whitelisting of the  production app-engine IPs as given by `dig -t TXT _netblocks.google.com @ns1.google.com`

Comment: I'd ask first if they have anything in that range blacklisted, or if they can explain why one fetch gets a 200 and the other a 500.